# How to expand subplots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, margins

I am trying to have many subplots (7*4 rows*col) using following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)

for i in range(28):
    plt.subplot(4, 7, i+1)
    plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It produces all subplots together but with wide margins around individual figures:

[image]

If I omit `tight_layout()` then they are closer together but have a large margin at top, bottom, right and left:

[image]

How can I reduce or remove extra space from between as well as around the figures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subplots_adjust` method, adjusting the `wspace` and `hspace` arguments as you see fit (width space and height space respectively):

```
for i in range(28):
    plt.subplot(4, 7, i+1)
    plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=1, hspace=1)
```

[image]

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html), these are "expressed as a fraction of the average axis width/height"

Comment: Setting `wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1` worked for me. But significant margins at top, bottom, right and especially left still remain. Is there any way to minimize them?

Comment: You can mess around with the `top` and `bottom` arguments. For instance, try `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1, top=0.95, bottom=0.05)`

Comment: I see that even 0.01 is working!

Comment: Glad I could help!